# Android Google calendar api 403 Forbidden Error on event insert

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am developing Android application that uses google calendar API. I followed standard exampled shown on [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) site. But I got error of 403 Forbidden every time.

My Code.

```html
public class CalendarActivityMain extends Activity
        implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {
    GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
    private TextView mOutputText;
    private Button mCallApiButton;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;

    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
    static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
    static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS = 1003;

    private static final String BUTTON_TEXT = "Call Google Calendar API";
    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
    private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY };

    /**
     * Create the main activity.
     * @param savedInstanceState previously saved instance data.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout activityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        activityLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        activityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        activityLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams tlp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        mCallApiButton = new Button(this);
        mCallApiButton.setText(BUTTON_TEXT);
        mCallApiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallApiButton.setEnabled(false);
                mOutputText.setText("");
                getResultsFromApi();
                mCallApiButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        activityLayout.addView(mCallApiButton);

        mOutputText = new TextView(this);
        mOutputText.setLayoutParams(tlp);
        mOutputText.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
        mOutputText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mOutputText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        mOutputText.setText(
                "Click the \'" + BUTTON_TEXT +"\' button to test the API.");
        activityLayout.addView(mOutputText);

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgress.setMessage("Calling Google Calendar API ...");

        setContentView(activityLayout);

        // Initialize credentials and service object.
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
    }



    /**
     * Attempt to call the API, after verifying that all the preconditions are
     * satisfied. The preconditions are: Google Play Services installed, an
     * account was selected and the device currently has online access. If any
     * of the preconditions are not satisfied, the app will prompt the user as
     * appropriate.
     */
    private void getResultsFromApi() {
        if (! isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            acquireGooglePlayServices();
        } else if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
            chooseAccount();
        } else if (! isDeviceOnline()) {
            mOutputText.setText("No network connection available.");
        } else {
            new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to set the account used with the API credentials. If an account
     * name was previously saved it will use that one; otherwise an account
     * picker dialog will be shown to the user. Note that the setting the
     * account to use with the credentials object requires the app to have the
     * GET_ACCOUNTS permission, which is requested here if it is not already
     * present. The AfterPermissionGranted annotation indicates that this
     * function will be rerun automatically whenever the GET_ACCOUNTS permission
     * is granted.
     */
    @AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS)
    private void chooseAccount() {
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
                this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
            String accountName = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
            if (accountName != null) {
                mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                getResultsFromApi();
            } else {
                // Start a dialog from which the user can choose an account
                startActivityForResult(
                        mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                        REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
            }
        } else {
            // Request the GET_ACCOUNTS permission via a user dialog
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    "This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts).",
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS,
                    Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
     * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
     * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
     * @param requestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
     * @param resultCode code indicating the result of the incoming
     *     activity result.
     * @param data Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
     *     activity result.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    mOutputText.setText(
                            "This app requires Google Play Services. Please install " +
                                    "Google Play Services on your device and relaunch this app.");
                } else {
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                        data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName =
                            data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        SharedPreferences settings =
                                getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                        editor.apply();
                        mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                        getResultsFromApi();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Respond to requests for permissions at runtime for API 23 and above.
     * @param requestCode The request code passed in
     *     requestPermissions(android.app.Activity, String, int, String[])
     * @param permissions The requested permissions. Never null.
     * @param grantResults The grant results for the corresponding permissions
     *     which is either PERMISSION_GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED. Never null.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(
                requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    /**
     * Callback for when a permission is granted using the EasyPermissions
     * library.
     * @param requestCode The request code associated with the requested
     *         permission
     * @param list The requested permission list. Never null.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    /**
     * Callback for when a permission is denied using the EasyPermissions
     * library.
     * @param requestCode The request code associated with the requested
     *         permission
     * @param list The requested permission list. Never null.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the device currently has a network connection.
     * @return true if the device has a network connection, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    /**
     * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date.
     * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
     *     date on this device; false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        return connectionStatusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to resolve a missing, out-of-date, invalid or disabled Google
     * Play Services installation via a user dialog, if possible.
     */
    private void acquireGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
            showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Display an error dialog showing that Google Play Services is missing
     * or out of date.
     * @param connectionStatusCode code describing the presence (or lack of)
     *     Google Play Services on this device.
     */
    void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
            final int connectionStatusCode) {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        Dialog dialog = apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(
                CalendarActivityMain.this,
                connectionStatusCode,
                REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
        dialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * An asynchronous task that handles the Google Calendar API call.
     * Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive.
     */
    private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService = null;
        private Exception mLastError = null;

        /*public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Android Quickstart")
                    .build();
        }*/

        public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential mCredential) {

            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();



            mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
                    .setApplicationName("Call Google Calendar API")
                    .build();
        }

        /**
         * Background task to call Google Calendar API.
         * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                getDataFromApi();
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Fetch a list of the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
         * @return List of Strings describing returned events.
         * @throws IOException
         */
        private void getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            /*// List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
            DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
            Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                    .setMaxResults(10)
                    .setTimeMin(now)
                    .setOrderBy("startTime")
                    .setSingleEvents(true)
                    .execute();
            List<Event> items = events.getItems();

            for (Event event : items) {
                DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
                if (start == null) {
                    // All-day events don't have start times, so just use
                    // the start date.
                    start = event.getStart().getDate();
                }
                eventStrings.add(
                        String.format("%s (%s)", event.getSummary(), start));
            }
            return eventStrings;*/
            Event event = new Event()
                    .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
                    .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
                    .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.");

            DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2017-05-28T09:00:00-07:00");
            EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                    .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                    .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
            event.setStart(start);

            DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2017-05-28T17:00:00-07:00");
            EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                    .setDateTime(endDateTime)
                    .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
            event.setEnd(end);

            String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"};
            event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

            EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
                    new EventAttendee().setEmail("lpage@example.com"),
                    new EventAttendee().setEmail("sbrin@example.com"),
            };
            event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));

            EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
                    new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
                    new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
            };
            Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                    .setUseDefault(false)
                    .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
            event.setReminders(reminders);

            String calendarId = "primary";
            event = mService.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
            System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mOutputText.setText("");
            mProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mProgress.hide();
        }
/*@Override
        protected Void onPostExecute() {
            mProgress.hide();
            *//*if (output == null || output.length() == 0) {
                mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
            } else {
                //output.add(0, "Data retrieved using the Google Calendar API:");

                mOutputText.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", output));
            }*//*
            return null;
        }*/

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (mLastError != null) {
                if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                    showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                            ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                    .getConnectionStatusCode());
                } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                    startActivityForResult(
                            ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                            CalendarActivityMain.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } else {
                    mOutputText.setText("The following error occurred:\n"
                            + mLastError.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                mOutputText.setText("Request cancelled.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```html
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
08-22 11:46:49.507 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err: {
08-22 11:46:49.507 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:   "code" : 403,
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     "domain" : "global",
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:   } ],
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:   "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err: }
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
08-22 11:46:49.508 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at com.ridhs.vaccinesample.CalendarActivityMain$MakeRequestTask.getDataFromApi(CalendarActivityMain.java:426)
08-22 11:46:49.509 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at com.ridhs.vaccinesample.CalendarActivityMain$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(CalendarActivityMain.java:352)
08-22 11:46:49.509 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at com.ridhs.vaccinesample.CalendarActivityMain$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(CalendarActivityMain.java:319)
08-22 11:46:49.509 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
08-22 11:46:49.509 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-22 11:46:49.509 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-22 11:46:49.509 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-22 11:46:49.509 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-22 11:46:49.509 2210-2345/com.ridhs.vaccinesample W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see you're trying to *create* an event, but you're sending your request with read-only scope.

Using the scope `CalendarScopes.CALENDAR` instead of `CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY` should solve the problem.

As an alternative, you could just use the `CalendarScopes.all()` method.

From its documentation:

> Returns an unmodifiable set that contains all scopes declared by this
>   class.